# Is it possible to disable a user to remove specific values in a select2 selectlist?

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have a situation where I add a few pre-selected values that a user should not be able to remove, hence I want to remove the "X" (remove) for those values.

I'm using the "Multi-select boxes (pillbox)" functionality and populate the dropdown with a few values that a user should not be able to remove.

Is that possible? I can't seem to find a way to do that after reading through the documentation.

```html
<select id="package-tags" multiple="multiple" name="TagsSelected">
    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="5b2b55b817c0f83e230000cf">Digital</option>
    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="5b2b55b817c0f83e230000d0">Analog</option>
    <option value="5b309ebd56f5c68749000001">Campaign</option>
    <option value="5b309ecd133db04c25000002">Packages</option>
</select>
```

```js
$("#package-tags").select2({
    allowClear: false,
    tags: true,
    width: '100%'
})
```

I wan't the disabled values to be selected but also it should not be able to remove those.

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Added the select list and javascript, although it's not much